# Android google maps - draggable Marker pops up

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using a setOnMarkerDragListener on my marker. Google describes the default behaviour like this

> Called when a marker starts being dragged. The marker's location can
>   be accessed via getPosition(); this position may be different to the
>   position prior to the start of the drag because the marker is popped
>   up above the touch point.

any idea how to override / disable this "popped up" thing or where to start to investigate?

Comment: want do you exactly want to do. do you want your previous location where the marker was placed before?

Comment: I want to use the setOnMarkerDragListener to have a longclick on the marker. After longclick a confirm-dialog should appear where the user confirms removing this marker. In this case I don't need the "pop up" effect.

Comment: If you just want to listen for a long-click on a marker you don't need to use a drag listener.

Comment: so what would be your solution for this?